# ElasticSearch - Filtering data returned from nested query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-query

I am have a set of data in the following structure:

```
[
    {
        "productId": "ProductId1",
        "customerNumbers": [
            "customer": {
                "name": "Prod1Cust1",
                "totalOrders": 23
            },
            "customer": {
                "name": "Prod2Cust1",
                "totalOrders": 5
            },
            "customer": {
                "name": "Prod3Cust1",
                "totalOrders": 5
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "productId": "ProductId2",
        "customerNumbers": [
            "customer": {
                "name": "Prod2Cust1",
                "totalOrders": 23
            },
            "customer": {
                "name": "Prod2Cust1",
                "totalOrders": 5
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

and I need to fetch all the records which have a **prefix** of "Prod1 as in **name** field(in the example avoid, only first record should be returned i.e. ProductId1). Also, when the data is returned, I need to just fetch just the customer number whose prefix is Prod1 i.e:

**Correct Output:**

```
{
        "productId": "ProductId1",
        "customerNumbers": [
            "customer": {
                "name": "Prod1Cust1",
                "totalOrders": 23
            }
        ]
    }
```

**Instead of:**

```
{
        "productId": "ProductId1",
        "customerNumbers": [
            "customer": {
                "name": "Prod1Cust1",
                "totalOrders": 23
            },
            "customer": {
                "name": "Prod2Cust1",
                "totalOrders": 5
            },
            "customer": {
                "name": "Prod3Cust1",
                "totalOrders": 5
            }
        ]
    }
```

I'm able to fetch the records whose **Name** prefix is "Prod1" using nested query coupled with MatchPhrasePrefixQuery (this returns me result with all the customer numbers). How can I further filter the data to get customer numbers whose **Name** prefix is "Prod1".

Following is my current query:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "sort": [
        {
            "name.keyword": {
                "missing": "_first",
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "nested": {
                                    "query": {
                                        "bool": {
                                            "must": [
                                                {
                                                    "match": {
                                                        "customerNumbers.name": {
                                                            "query": "Prod1",
                                                            "type": "phrase_prefix"
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "path": "customerNumbers"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

P.S: I'm using ElasticSearch 5.x with Nest.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-inner-hits):

```
PUT products
{"mappings":{"_doc":{"properties":{"customerNumbers":{"type":"nested"}}}}}

POST products/_doc
{"productId":"ProductId1","customerNumbers":[{"name":"Prod1Cust1","totalOrders":23},{"name":"Prod2Cust1","totalOrders":5},{"name":"Prod3Cust1","totalOrders":5}]}

POST products/_doc
{"productId":"ProductId2","customerNumbers":[{"name":"Prod2Cust1","totalOrders":23},{"name":"Prod2Cust1","totalOrders":5}]}
```

```
GET products/_search
{
  "_source": "inner_hits", 
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "customerNumbers",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "match_phrase_prefix": {
                            "customerNumbers.name": {
                              "query": "Prod1"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "inner_hits": {}
                }

              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

yielding the following hits

```
[
  {
    "_index":"products",
    "_type":"_doc",
    "_id":"tyQGo3EBdiyDG0RsTa0N",
    "_score":0.9808292,
    "_source":{

    },
    "inner_hits":{
      "customerNumbers":{
        "hits":{
          "total":1,
          "max_score":0.9808292,
          "hits":[
            {
              "_index":"products",
              "_type":"_doc",
              "_id":"tyQGo3EBdiyDG0RsTa0N",
              "_nested":{
                "field":"customerNumbers",
                "offset":0
              },
              "_score":0.9808292,
              "_source":{
                "name":"Prod1Cust1",         <-----
                "totalOrders":23
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you @jzzfs for your reply. I did implement the logic as described by you; I'm able to fetch the inner hits, but it just contains a subset of the total result (I've set the Size attribute of inner_hits to max value). Any idea, why?

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? A single customer from a huge list of non-relevant customers?

Comment: yeah, but, in the test case which I'm executing, there are around 70 customer that satisfy the prefix condition, but the inner hits count is around 50. I'm not sure, why the other 20 records are not part of inner hits.

Comment: what limit did you set in the inner hits? What's your `max value`?

Comment: I'm using C# (NEST NuGet package) and have set the limit to Int32.MaxValue.

Comment: Strange indeed. What's your es.yaml `index.max_inner_result_window` setting? Alternatively, dump your docs in a JSON where I can replicate it.